# how to create functional/method loop javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor

i have an app the automatically insert data to mongodb after calling an api in jive, my problem is the response is paginated.

```
var getAPICall=function(apiLink){
  console.log(apiLink);
  var response = HTTP.get(apiLink, {
             headers: {
                 Authorization: getAPIToken()
             }
    });
  return response;
}

var getAPIToken = function(){
  var token = HTTP.post("https://api.jivesoftware.com/analytics/v1/auth/login?clientId=fakeclientid.i&clientSecret=fakesecret.s");
  //console.log(token);
  return token.content;
}
```

the response looks like this.

```
{"paging":{"next":"https://cloudalytics-api-phx.prod.jivehosted.com:443/analytics/v2/export/activity/lastday?startIndex=100&count=100&show-all=true","itemsPerPage":100,"totalCount":164406,"currentPage":1,"totalPages":1645}, list: [{....}]}
```

which has `next`, `currentPage` and `totalPage` field

im planning to do a loop for the `next` page function and stop when `totalPage` is equal to `currentPage`

im doing this

```
var res = getAPICall(baseline);    
_.each(res.data.list, function(item) {
    console.log(item.uuid);
    Reports.upsert({"uuid":item.uuid},{$set :item});
    });


var totalPage = res.data.paging.totalPage; 
for(var current = res.data.paging.currentPage ;  current <= totalPage ;) {
    var res = getAPICall(res.data.paging.next );    
        _.each(res.data.list, function(item) {
            console.log(item.uuid);
            Reports.upsert({"uuid":item.uuid},{$set :item});
            });
}
```

but this statement only runs until the next page with infinite loop. any ways i can do this better with functional approach?

im new in javascript please hammer me.

thanks!

Comment: Can I use babel in an answer?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes please. you can. im still trying to get an idea.

Comment: @atinder yes. should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be pretty simple with recursion.

```
var myFunction = function(baseline){
  var res = getAPICall(baseline);
  _.each(res.data.list, function(item) {
    console.log(item.uuid);
    Reports.upsert({"uuid":item.uuid},{$set :item});
  });
  if (res.data.paging.currentPage != res.data.paging.totalPage) {
    myFunction(res.data.paging.next)
  }
}    

myFunction(baseline);
```